# Как убрать скролл в браузере mozilla?

Tags: html, css

в opera и chrome скролл убирается

а в mozilla firefox нет

```css
div {
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

div::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}


div::-moz-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus ut quisquam in, minima illum nostrum consectetur. Numquam, rerum, dolorem ducimus possimus maxime fugiat ut modi obcaecati dolor explicabo odio ratione.  </p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus ut quisquam in, minima illum nostrum consectetur. Numquam, rerum, dolorem ducimus possimus maxime fugiat ut modi obcaecati dolor explicabo odio ratione.  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Проверь свойство `overflow`... Нету у него параметра none! `hidden` знаю, `auto` знаю, а none первый раз слышу https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

Comment: @Eugene X, абсолютно ничего не меняется. Заменила

Comment: overflow-y: hidden;

Comment: @Pavel Nazarian, спасибо огромное. Работает. Можете написать в ответ, пожалуйста? отмечу решением

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В браузере mozilla firefox убрать скроллбар можно при помощи:

```
scrollbar-width: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотели убрать вертикальный скролл, то у вас стоит `overflow-y: auto;` вместо `overflow-y: hidden;`

`overflow: hidden;` скрывает сразу по обоим осям